# Sudoku java, efficient way for 4x4 sudoku

Tags: java

I'm making a sudoku program and i have establish 2D array to represent the 4x4 grid like sudoku:

```
    int getNumber (String str) 
    {

     if (str.equals ("")) 
    {
        return 0;
    } 

    return Integer.parseInt (str);
    } 

    int[][] sudoku = new int [4][4];


    sudoku[0][0] = getNumber(t1.getText());
    sudoku[1][0] = getNumber(t2.getText());
    sudoku[2][0] = getNumber(t5.getText());
    sudoku[3][0] = getNumber(t6.getText());
    sudoku[0][1] = getNumber(t3.getText());
    sudoku[1][1] = getNumber(t4.getText());
    sudoku[2][1] = getNumber(t7.getText());
    sudoku[3][1] = getNumber(t8.getText());
    sudoku[0][2] = getNumber(t9.getText());
    sudoku[1][2] = getNumber(t10.getText());
    sudoku[2][2] = getNumber(t13.getText());
    sudoku[3][2] = getNumber(t14.getText());
    sudoku[0][3] = getNumber(t11.getText());
    sudoku[1][3] = getNumber(t12.getText());
    sudoku[2][3] = getNumber(t15.getText());
    sudoku[3][3] = getNumber(t16.getText());
```

so, my point is you know how there can be same number horizontally, vertically, and the box(in this case 2x2). Since i don't want to write bunch of if statement comparing one index to other index hundred times. Maybe you guys can help me make a loop that compares vertically, horizontally, and for squares. Im planning to make sudoku like this:

```
 [][] [][]
 [][] [][]

 [][] [][]
 [][] [][]      
 //each square representing a spot for number(4x4 sudoku)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view the algorithm becomes simpler if you use a 1D array rather than 2D. It's trivial to print it as a table irrespective of the data structure.

Using Java 8 a possible solution could look like:

```
private static final int SIZE = 4;
private static final int BOX = 2;
private int[] sudoko = new int[SIZE * SIZE];

private boolean hasDuplicate(int pos) {
    int value = sudoko[pos];
    return IntStream.range(0, SIZE * SIZE)
        .filter(p -> p != pos)
        .filter(p -> sameRow(p, pos) || sameCol(p, pos) || sameBox(p, pos))
        .anyMatch(p -> sudoko[p] == value);
}

private boolean sameRow(int pos1, int pos2) {
    return pos1 / DIM == pos2 / DIM;
}

private boolean sameCol(int pos1, int pos2) {
    return pos1 % DIM == pos2 % DIM;
}

private boolean sameBox(int pos1, int pos2) {
    return pos1 / SIZE / BOX == pos2 / SIZE / BOX && pos1 % SIZE / BOX == pos2 % SIZE / BOX;
}
```

You can use the same algorithm with a 2D array but you'll need something more complex than an `IntStream`.